# Using multiple .env files in Svelte/Sveltekit

Tags: node.js, svelte, sveltekit

I am familiar with Vite's very easy `.env` setup where you can have `.env`, `.env.production`, etc. With Sveltekit's "new" private/public/dyanmic stuff, I am not sure how it works now. Currently I have a `.env` file with dev info but I would like to have

1. `.env.dev`
2. `.env.integration`
3. `.env.production`

Or something like that. Although I cannot figure out how to get this to work with Sveltekit, or really even where to define the env. I am not 100% positive if it uses NODE_ENV to determine the environment either.

Comment: Don't do that. Dotenv's [own FAQ](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#-faq) discourages it. Rather than rebuilding the app for every environment it needs to run in, promote an _artifact_ and configure at deploy or run time). I've written more about this here: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Sep/19/spa-config.html.

Comment: As one possible solution, because environment files just set environment variables, you can simply do `source .env.production`, or similar UNIX command, before running node on a production server.

Comment: You could add a prefix to the file name, such as: ```PROD_XYZ``` for produciton and ```DEV_XYZ``` for development